# Android 2.3.3 app doesn't work in 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

I was working on a project which I developed in Android 2.3.3.

I want to continue developing it on Android 4.0.3, but it doesn't work.

When I delete `usesminsdk` from manifest file, it works.

Is there any other way to do it? Is my way healthy?

```
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)

06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:270)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:215)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:751)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:688)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at tr.edu.ege.yanyanayiz.LoginController.getProfileInformation(LoginController.java:116)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at tr.edu.ege.yanyanayiz.LoginController.startNewIntent(LoginController.java:50)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at tr.edu.ege.yanyanayiz.LoginController$2.onComplete(LoginController.java:95)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook$1.onComplete(Facebook.java:354)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.facebook.android.FbDialog$FbWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(FbDialog.java:144)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:224)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:324)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-19 09:19:33.122: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please show us your manifest, and tell us which build target you have specified in properties, also "It doesn't work" is a bit vague please provide the logcat of the error etc.

Comment: "doesn't work" is a rather useless description of the problem.

Comment: sorry, you are right. I edited my question

Answer (score 4):

### [Why Does My App Crash On Ice Cream Sandwich?](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

I just wrote a blog post this morning on the exact same topic. HoneyComb and ICS is much more strict when it comes to abusing the UI thread. Check to see that you aren't performing any expensive operations on the UI thread, and if you are wrap them in a `Thread` or an `AsyncTask` instead.

Answer (score 3):

i run into this problem too. I have two method to run away from it:
1. put the network code into another thread, to avoid NetworkOnMainThreadException
2. modify AndroidManifest.xml from A) to B):

A)

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

B)

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="7"
 />
```

and now it works!

Comment: Thanks a lot man......just want to give u a tight hug....u saved my whole year...... :P :)

Answer (score 1):

make sure your manifest tag is like so :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

then

1. Right Click Project
2. Properties
3. Android
4. Check Android 4.0.3
5. Hit ok.

You should be good to go but you might need to Clean Project or Right Click Project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties after that.

Comment: I did what you said, but I am still getting that error, which are shown in logcat. I edited my question. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hi I guess this is because you are accessing network(also check for your webservices) in main UI thread make use of AsyncTask in your code and errors will go not an issue with manifest file no point of changing anything in Manifest.